# FromIterator trait not implemented for iterator of custom type

Tags: rust, traits

I'm playing with postgres_tokio. I'm querying some data (the locations of some pubs in London). I have a `Pub` struct. I'd like to build a `Vec<Pub>`  from the result of the query:

```rust
    let data = client
        .query(&stmt, &[&user_pos.lon, &user_pos.lat, &DST_NEARBY])
        .await
        .unwrap()
        .iter()
        // TODO: we could implement the trait `FromIterator<&tokio_postgres::Row>` for `Vec<Pub>`
        // .map(|row| Pub::from(row))
        .collect::<Vec<Pub>>();
```

The snippet above shows how I query the data. The call to `iter()` gets us a `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&tokio_postgres::Row>`.

Here is the `Pub` struct:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Pub {
    pub name: String,
    pub lon: f64,
    pub lat: f64,
}

impl From<&Row> for Pub {
    fn from(row: &Row) -> Self {
        let raw_name: String = row.get("name");
        Pub {
            name: String::from(raw_name.trim()),
            lon: row.get("lon"),
            lat: row.get("lat"),
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented the `From` trait for a `Row`, so I can convert a DB `Row` to a `Pub` easily. In the query snippet above, I commented `.map(|row| Pub::from(row))` but this works perfectly.

Now for educational purposes, I'd like to collect directly to a `Vec<Pub>`, but I'm getting this error:

```
33   |         .collect::<Vec<Pub>>();
     |          ^^^^^^^ value of type `Vec<Pub>` cannot be built from `std::iter::Iterator<Item=&tokio_postgres::Row>`
     |
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<&tokio_postgres::Row>` is not implemented for `Vec<Pub>`
     = help: the trait `FromIterator<T>` is implemented for `Vec<T>`
```

I don't understand why it's not compiling. The help message says `` FromIterator<T>` is implemented for `Vec<T> ``, and I implemented the `impl From<&Row> for Pub` trait. I'd have hope that Rust could deduce how to convert to a `Vec<Pub>` from these two traits, but apparently I missed something.

My question is then: is there a way to combine these two traits, or do I have to specifically implement `FromIterator<&tokio_postgres::Row>` for `Vec<Pub>` ?

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR;

Don't implement `From<Row>`  use `#[derive(FromSql)]` from the related [postgres_type conversion crate](https://docs.rs/postgres-types/latest/postgres_types/).

## Using rust type signatures and `where` constraints to decipher the API.

How to figure this stuff out can be a bit tough in rust. I know I've struggled with it :-)

So I figured I'd share how i figured out what do.

First let's look at the signature of `Row::get` in docs.rs:

```rust
 pub fn get<'a, I, T>(&'a self, idx: I) -> T
    where
        I: RowIndex + fmt::Display,
        T: FromSql<'a>;
```

When we look at the bound `T: FromSql<'a>` on the return type T we know that it's something we want to be able to do; Now we can go look at FromSql (and may be hunt for a `ToSql`? because why not :-))

Looking at the traits documentation in postgres_tokio we find:

```
    BorrowToSql
    FromSql
    FromSqlOwned
    ToSql
```

Here you'd wonder, can I `#[derive(FromSql)]` etc. easily; because that would be a pretty common interface to expect from the library devs ;)

Okay so this doesn't seem to be available per`docs.rs`;

### We found nothing!

Now here things become a bit hairy when it comes to rust documentation; It's always a good idea to not only look at the `docs.rs` documentation, but to also checkout the repository for any examples or other tit-bits of information.

### Lo!

When we look github [we find that there is a related 'derive' crate to help with post_gres types](https://docs.rs/postgres-types/latest/postgres_types/) to derive ToSql / FromSql that can help; but even if that wasn't the case we could look at `tests/` folder or embedded tests in the worst case scenario to try and figure out how we can do what we are trying to use.

Comment: > Don't implement From<Row> use #[derive(FromSql)] from the related postgres_type conversion crate.
I don't think this works here. To implement it for `Pub`, I'd have to work with `fn from_sql(_: &Type, raw: &[u8])`, while the data I have comes from a select query, not a nice clean postgres type. I'm really looking to deserialize a row record.